# How to view last run shell command via cmd.exe through a HKEY_CURRENT_USER.reg file?

Tags: forensics

I'm working on improving my security skills and a challenge I have is a .reg file which is HKEY_CURRENT_USER. I need to find what the last run command on the box was.

Comment: In your question title you mention cmd.exe but you ask for a registry key which records last run command...there is a registry key that stores the last 26 commands that a user (local or remote) executed via run (the system tool).  I know of no such registry key for cmd.exe history.

Comment: @JohnLancaster I Googled "HKEY_CURRENT_USER last run command" and got a lot of hits ....

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. `cmd.exe` does not save history on the registry or a log file.

Open `cmd.exe` and press `Up`. What shows up? Nothing. That's because there's no history...

Answer (score -1):

In a DOS shell, type an uncommon but verified command and press enter.
Once the command has executed, find it in the registry with regedit, starting from the hive you specified.
If you find one item that matches your command, you can be sure you've found the way to reach your goal; if not, your goal is impossibile to achieve in terms you specified.

Comment: DOS has not been a part of Windows for a long time. You mean the command window.